# Material UI Tooltip title text content has a button that opens a dialog, dialog disappear after opening

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to use the tooltip which has a title text content, say:

```
title={<>
Some text
<Button onClick={onOpen}>Click Me!</Button>
</>}
```

and that button's onClick will set the state to open a mui dialog, i've also set the Tooltip's interactive prop to be true. When the button inside the Tooltip's title content is click, the dialog pops up briefly then goes away. I believe that is also due to Tooltip fading away using the interactive prop.

Is there anyway to get the dialog to stay meanwhile having the tooltip title content disappear? Is material ui's tooltip component meant to be use this way?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please Share your code of `onOpen` method and how are you updating the state and all.

Comment: Yes we need the code for the modal, and the state variable that conrols it